# Dynamically create folder and upload file in multipart request Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I'm trying to dynamically create folders when user loads a file (this is because I need to store every user files separately so there's no conflict if a file is deleted) and create the file path in my computer so I can store it in my many to many relationship table in the database (users can have many files and many files can belong to different users, that's why I can't store them together) but I cannot get this with my current logic. I could create different name with timestamps but it would get messy.

I'm using `multer` and `Express`. The form data that's been sent is the one on the attached image.

[image: formdata]

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const multer = require('multer');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const fs = require('fs');


router.use(bodyParser.json());
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));


let storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      //req.body is empty
      let path = `./public/uploads/${req.body.id}`;
      if (!fs.existsSync(path)) {
          fs.mkdirSync(filesDir);
      }
      cb(null, path);
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, `${file.originalname}`)
       }
})

let upload = multer({storage:storage});
var cpUpload = upload.fields([{ name: 'file', maxCount: 1}, { name: 'id'}]);

router.post('/uploadSingFile', cpUpload,(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body); req.body is ok
    res.send({status:200});
});
```

Somehow the request object doesn't have the body in the destination function but does in the post request. I thought this would work given the way middlewares work in Node, the storage function should have the same request object that the post request has.

Answer (score 0):

You can use newly generated `uuid` for filenames to have it unique inside the folder. For the folder name, instead of getting it from request body(`req.body.id`), use something like `userId` which can make sure the folder belongs to particular user.